# Magento 2 - How to change position of Sign in and My Account link?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, toplinks, link

How can i move account creation link and sign in link after the search box.

Need Help

[image]

Comment: i want sign links down  nearby cart

Answer (score 1):

You can edit by layout like this way. Add this code below inside body tag in default.xml layout

```
 <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true" /> 

 <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <container name="sign-in-div" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="signin-wrap" after="logo">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-custom" template="Magento_Theme::account/link/authorization.phtml" />
    </container>
 </referenceContainer>
```

file template    account/link/authorization.phtml copy in Magento_Customer to your theme or module for apply new template

Comment: any video files are available to do  i can't  understand this ( file template account/link/authorization.phtml copy in Magento_Customer to your theme or module for apply new template)

Comment: You can copy to your theme follow path magentoroot/app/design/frontend/YourVendorName/theme_name/Magento_Customer/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml <= this file template will override current original template if module Customer available . My code above you can put into any file layout (*.xml) default.xml will apply to all pages in current frontend. See theme luma as your example (you can find it inside vendor directory)

Comment: im added the above your code in default.xml and also  im copy authorization.phtml  <= then after wher can i paste plz describe

Comment: I am facing the same issue and your answer is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Please add below line in default.xml layout

```
 <move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.search"/>
```

Than clean cache : php bin/magento c:f

Comment: I am facing the same issue and your answer is not working for me